# How to write a method to compare a vector and aggregate?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector. I want to compare it with an aggregate to see if they are equal. For example

```
vector<int> v{0, 1, 2};

bool b = equal(v, {0, 1, 2}); // how to write a method to implement it???
```

Comment: [Why write anything?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal)

Comment: `{0, 1, 2}` is not an aggregate, it's a brace-enclosed list.  I assume you mean that you want to check the vector is the same as a vector initialized from that list would be.

Comment: @user4581301 `std::equal` requires 3 iterators so it can't be used with any syntax remotely resembling OP's pseudocode

Comment: Yeah. Got me there.

Comment: `vector<int> v{0, 1, 2}; bool b = (v == vector<int>{0, 1, 2});` you know this is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just compare them by `==` operator.

```
bool v_equal(const std::vector<int>& v1, const std::vector<int>&v2) {
    return v1==v2;    
}
```

Call the function like:

```
bool isEqual = v_equal(v1,{0, 1, 2});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use an `std::initializer_list` for this purpose, eg

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool equal(const std::vector<int>& v1, const std::initializer_list<int>& v2) {
  return std::equal(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> data1 = {1,2,3,4};
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << equal(data1, {1,2,3,4}) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can even use template template arguments to write a generic function which is able to evaluate two collections as long as they provide iterators and `operator==` for contained types, something like:

```
template<typename T, template<typename...> class C1, typename U, template<typename...> class C2>
bool is_equal(const C1<T>& v1, const C2<U>& v2) {
  return std::equal(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
}
```

But to make deduction work with `emphasized textstd::initializer_list` you need to cast them appropriately then, like `(std::initializer_list<int>){1,2,3,4}`.

The `std::equal` overload which accepts 4 iterators is C++14 only though, if you don't have access to it you must check that length is the same.

Comment: You also need to check the lengths are the same - this will report `true` if the initializer list is longer than the vector but starting with the same elements; and cause undefined behaviour if the list is shorter.